# Tensorflow With Context Manager vs. With Session

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand how a `with` block behaves in the above scenarios. I  assume to always have one graph and one session only. I understand that I have (at least?) 2 ways to work using a session in a `with` block:

**Example 1 :** using [`as_default()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#as_default) that creates a context manager:
[Same documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#as_default) says:

> Use with the `with` keyword to specify that calls to
>   `tf.Operation.run` or `tf.Tensor.eval` should be executed in this
>   session.

```
# Create session
sess = tf.Session()
# Enter with block on a new context manager
with sess.as_default():
  # Train: Following line should result calling tf.Operation.run
  sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x: x_train, y: y_train)
  # Eval: Following line should result calling tf.Tensor.eval
  sess.run([loss], feed_dict={x: x_eval, y: y_eval)
```

**Example 2 :** with block on session as stated in [same documentation in a  lower section](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#as_default):

> Alternatively, you can use `with tf.Session():` to create a session that
>   is automatically closed on exiting the context, including when an
>   uncaught exception is raised.

```
# Enter with block on session instead of Context Manager
with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Train: Following line seems calling tf.Operation.run as per my test
  sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x: x_train, y: y_train)
  # Eval: Following is unclear
  sess.run([loss], feed_dict={x: x_eval, y: y_eval)
```

I would like to understand what is the correct usage as I see GitHub examples of both cases but of course without the results. In my tests both Example 1 and 2 works for training. For evaluation it seems there is a difference that I can't understand. It exceeds my knowledge to browse the Tensorflow source. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do slightly different things, so each may or may not be correct depending on the usage. [`tf.Session.as_default()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#as_default) will just ensure that the session is set as the default ones, so calls to `eval` and `run` will use that session by default:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    print(sess is tf.get_default_session())  # True
```

However, as stated in the documentation, [`tf.Session.as_default()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#as_default) will *not* automatically close the session after the `with` block. If you want that, you can use the session itself as the context manager:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Do something with the session
sess.run([])  # RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

However, although (from my point of view) not clearly documented, using a session as context manager *also* makes it the default session.

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess is tf.get_default_session())  # True
```

What is the point of [`tf.Session.as_default()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#as_default), then? Well, simply when you want to temporarily make a session the default one but you do not one to close it after that (in which case you should manually close it later, or use it as an outer context manager). This is probably most relevant when you have more than one open session. Consider the following case:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess1, tf.Session() as sess2:
    print(sess2 is tf.get_default_session())  # True
```

Here `sess2` is the default because its context was added later (it can be considered to be "inner" to the context created by `sess1`). But now maybe you want to make `sess1` the default for a while. However you can not use `sess1` itself as context manager again:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess1, tf.Session() as sess2:
    # Do something with sess2
    with sess1:
        # RuntimeError: Session context managers are not re-entrant.
        #               Use `Session.as_default()` if you want to enter
        #               a session multiple times.
```

So you can switch between one and other default sessions with [`tf.Session.as_default()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#as_default):

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess1, tf.Session() as sess2:
    with sess1.as_default():
        # Do something with sess1
    with sess2.as_default():
        # Do something with sess2
        # This is not really needed because sess2 was the default
        # in the outer context but you can add it to be explicit
# Both sessions are closed at the end of the outer context
```

Of course, you can be extra explicit even with one session, if you want:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess, sess.as_default():
    # ...
```

Personally, I have never used [`tf.Session.as_default()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#as_default) in my actual code, but then again I have rarely needed to use multiple sessions, and I prefer to use [`tf.Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) instead of relying on the default session anyway, but that is mostly a matter of personal taste I suppose.